# Duplication of Comments in my database, how can I fix it?

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I have some problem that every time I refresh the page it duplicates the last comment. I tried with redirecting command:

```
header("location:../../index.php");
```

but it gives me this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/timpovodnik/gymshark.timpovodnik.xyz/header.php:87) in
>   /home/timpovodnik/gymshark.timpovodnik.xyz/PHP/comments.php on line
>   9'.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    function setComments($conn) { // Funkcija, ki jo kasneje kličem v LoseFat in GainMuscles datoteki //zraven dodamo se spremenljivko $conn, ki je iz datoteke baza.php
        if(isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) { // Če kliknemo na gumb zažene kodo
            $uid = $_POST['uid'];
            $date = $_POST['date'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO komentarji (uime, sporocilo, datum, uporabnik_id, program_id, objava_id) VALUES ('$uid', '$message', '$date', '1', '1', '1')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // IZVEDE v BAZI
            header("location:../index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }

    function getComments($conn) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM komentarji";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // IZVEDE v BAZI
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { // da v tabelo in jo shrani v $row
            echo "<div class='row'>";
                echo "<div class='comment-box'>";
                    echo $row['uime']."<br>";
                    echo $row['datum']."<br>";
                    echo nl2br($row['sporocilo']);
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This warning usually occurs when calling Header function after writing output, e. g. with print or echo.

Comment: To add onto what @MSTRmt said, you could even get this error if you have any HTML (even blank lines) before your PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it and also added Mysqli functions to it.

Thank you for all of the suggestions.

```
<?php
include 'baza.php';

    if(isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) { // Če kliknemo na gumb zažene kodo
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO komentarji (uime, sporocilo, datum) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    header("Location: ../loseFat.php?error=sqlerror"); // Če stavek ne dela
                    exit();
            }
            else {        
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $uid, $message, $date); 
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // Executa stavek v DB

            header("Location: ../loseFat.php?comment=success");
            exit();
        }
    }


function getComments($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM komentarji";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // IZVEDE v BAZI
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { // da v tabelo in jo shrani v $row
        echo "<div class='row'>";
            echo "<div class='comment-box'>";
                echo $row['uime']."<br>";
                echo $row['datum']."<br>";
                echo nl2br($row['sporocilo']);
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

?>